# How to deploy changes in an existing Progress PASOE aplication when some method is added

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a deployed application in Progress 4GL PASOE that is working in Production, but now we had to add a new method to the Business Entity class. We did it locally with Developer Studio and, after restarting the instance, it works as expected. However, I don´t know how to apply this changes to Production. I have already copied the .r/.cls files to the corresponding openedge folder and also the service json file with the catalog to the webapp folder. I have restarted the pasoe instance (tcman stop/tcman start) and restarted service, but if I make a request through Postman it raises a 500 error:

[image: Postman request]

What else should we have to do? Is it necessary to delete the instance and do the whole deploy again to just add a new method?

The log file is throwing the following exception:

```
    2021-06-16T16:44:30.500+02:00 WARN  [thd-1] nynweb:r:0000000b o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for usuari has thrown exception, unwinding now 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

"usuari" is a table which is in the catalogue indeed.

Please let me know if you need some clarifying data to fully understand my problem.

Many thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to add new methods to existing classes, I update the classes in the application directory and export the services again by OpenEdge, creating a `ROOT.zip`. I always use the incremental deploy so I delete the agents and then, when calling the created method, it will respond.

A tip to check if the method is published is important to access `http://server:port/rest/`; there you will see the catalogs that are published and also if your new method is available.

[image: Catalogs Available]